# Cannot seed HABTM join table when an alias is used

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a client and worker model. A worker can blacklist a client. If blacklisted, the client and worker will never be paired together again. In the worker model I have,

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :blacklisted_clients, class_name: 'Client',
  join_table: 'blacklisted_clients_workers',
  association_foreign_key: 'blacklisted_client_id'
```

and in the client model I have,

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :workers,
  join_table: 'blacklisted_clients_workers',
  foreign_key: 'blacklisted_client_id'
```

The join table, `blacklisted_clients_workers`, consists of two columns, `worker_id` and `blacklisted_client_id`. I have tried to seed the association with,

```
Worker.create!(
  blacklisted_clients: BlacklistedClient.where(id: (1..200).to_a.shuffle.take(3)),
)
```

When I do I get an error that says

```
NameError: uninitialized constant BlacklistedClient
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you write **BlacklistedClient.where(....)** active support will look for the BlacklistedClient **model** which is your Client model.

You have create a relationship as blacklisted_clients for Clients not model.

Try to crate the same with **Client** instead of **BlacklistedClient**.

Comment: If I use `blacklisted_clients: Client.where(id: (1..200).to_a.shuffle.take(3)`, the error goes away, but nothing is seeded into the join table.

Comment: It is because your query is returning **blank**. more over **blacklisted_clients:** if it a field of your worker model it should be **blacklisted_client_id:** and then some value. one more thing **Client.create!(...)** will create on record at a time so you need to **have a loop** which take client id one by one and insert a record in worker model.

Comment: Problem solved - VK29 is correct. The line `blacklisted_clients: BlacklistedClient.where(id: (1..200).to_a.shuffle.take(3))`, should be `blacklisted_clients: Client.where(id: (1..200).to_a.shuffle.take(3))`. The other problem I had was that I created the client model after I created the worker model in the seed file. So the client model was empty when I tried to create the join table. I simply moved seeding the client model above seeding the worker model and everything is fine.

Comment: VK29 is not correct about using a loop. Client.where(id: []) can accept an array. `(1..200).to_a.shuffle.take(3)` does just that. I have created 200 clients prior to doing this. `(1..200).to_a.shuffle.take(3)` gives me a random array with 3 ids between 1 and 200. The SQL generated from it is `SELECT "clients".id FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."id" IN (153, 97, 166)` as an example.

Comment: I am happy that I was able to help you. :) and thank for random array thing...I was aware of it not able to recollect it at that point of time. still thanks for the info. @RamJet